# Group by query not returning all values

Tags: mysql

I am trying to sum columns to display statistics on a sports website. My mysql query is

```
SELECT s.schoolid, s.season, s.playerid, SUM(s.serviceaces) AS sumAces, SUM(s.attackkills) AS sumKills, SUM(s.assists) AS sumAssists, p.fname, p.lname 
FROM `stats` AS s 
LEFT JOIN `players` AS p ON p.id = s.playerid 
GROUP BY s.playerid 
HAVING s.schoolid = 2 AND s.season = 2015
```

This will give me 9 records. It should give me 12, as there are 12 players on team 2, and all have stats entered. If I change my query to a simple select query of

```
SELECT s.*, p.fname, p.lname 
FROM `stats` AS s 
LEFT JOIN `players` AS p ON p.id = s.playerid 
WHERE s.schoolid = 2 AND s.season = 2015
```

I return 24 records. This makes sense as there are two games worth of stats entered for this team of 12.

What am I doing wrong when I try to sum my columns and group by player?

Edit
Here is an sql fiddle link - http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e5cf5/1/0)

I found the problem, the missing people have stats from 2014. I will read up on Ollie's link to see if that is my problem.

So it appears my solution is as easy as adding a WHERE s.season = 2015 AND s.schoolid = 2 for a final query of

```
SELECT s.schoolid, s.season, s.playerid, SUM(s.serviceaces) AS sumAces, SUM(s.attackkills) AS sumKills, SUM(s.assists) AS sumAssists, p.fname, p.lname 
FROM `stats` AS s 
LEFT JOIN `players` AS p ON p.id = s.playerid
WHERE s.season = 2015
GROUP BY s.playerid
```

Missed Hitesh's answer as I was editing this. He got it right.

Comment: You may be misusing the pernicious MySQL extension to GROUP BY. Read this.  https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/group-by-handling.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this type of questions please post the table schema and sample record dump and desired outcome so we can test.
I think this can help you.

```
SELECT s.schoolid, s.season, s.playerid, SUM(s.serviceaces) AS sumAces, SUM(s.attackkills) AS sumKills, SUM(s.assists) AS sumAssists, p.fname, p.lname 
    FROM `stats` AS s 
    LEFT JOIN `players` AS p ON p.id = s.playerid 
    WHERE s.schoolid = 2 AND s.season = 2015
    GROUP BY s.playerid
```

Answer (score 0):

Switch your `from` and `left join` clauses - you want to drive the query from the `players`' side and display `null`s where the stats are missing, not the other way round:

```
SELECT    s.schoolid,
          s.season,
          s.playerid,
          SUM(s.serviceaces) AS sumAces,
          SUM(s.attackkills) AS sumKills,
          SUM(s.assists) AS sumAssists,
          p.fname,
          p.lname 
FROM      `players` AS p 
LEFT JOIN `stats` AS s ON p.id = s.playerid 
GROUP BY  s.playerid 
HAVING    s.schoolid = 2 AND s.season = 2015
```

Comment: Good thought, but no go. One of the players that is missing has a player id of 9874. So if I do a simple query of

    SELECT * FROM `stats` WHERE `playerid` = 9874 AND `schoolid` = 2 AND `season` = 2015

I get two rows of data

Comment: What's different about player 9874? You won't get his data if the JOIN can't satisfy the request to put a name to his id?  Or please show us some data - sql fiddle or otherwise.